# AWT version of processing

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, processing

I am trying to implement processing on my server using Servlet (basically using the method in processing to generate a image and display on the web), but failed with the Applet version of processing and will not try the js version (don't want to leak the code)

So I am wondering if there is some quick ways to implement the processing on Servlet like AWT version of processing, or will it be possible for rewriting the AWT version in a quick time?

Thanks.

Comment: Processing is a programming language based on Java Applet, and there is also js and Android version of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make a ton of sense. At its core, Processing is just a Java library, which you can use like any other Java library. Just include the Processing jar on your classpath, and you can use Processing classes and methods.

However, it doesn't make a lot of sense to use the graphical aspect of Processing (which is pretty much all of it) on the server. The only thing I can really think of is if you want to draw to a PImage and then pass that to a client. But that wouldn't involve any of the rigmarole you're talking about.

To put it simply, you shouldn't have to "re-implement" Processing at all. Just include the Processing jar on your classpath, and then use it like you would any other server-side Java library. But I'm skeptical about why you think you need to do this in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I will use processing on server is that I'm required to build a website that will generate a very complex image to the user and such generating functions have already been written by processing. That's right that I could use processing library by simply add the JAR, but the whole processing code is based on Applet so that means I have to run Java code on client's browser, the Java security warning will stop such operation and is really a bad use experience. So I am looking for a way to run the code on my server, actually I'm re-writing the code hope will not take time.

Comment: You're going to have to translate your Processing sketch into a Java class that extends PApplet. That shouldn't be that hard, since Processing is 90% Java anyway. Then just include that class (and the Processing jar) on your server's classpath, and call the code like you'd call any other Java program.